# Script printed in Wordpress Metabox?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm seeing a script being printed in each text metabox on my WordPress site:

```js
if (
  (function rt() {
    return (
      !!window.Ember ||
      !!window.Vue ||
      !!window.Meteor ||
      !(!window.React && !document.querySelector("[data-reactroot], [data-reactid]")) ||
      !!(
        window.angular ||
        document.querySelector(".ng-binding, [ng-app], [data-ng-app], [ng-controller], [data-ng-controller], [ng-repeat], [data-ng-repeat]") ||
        document.querySelector('script[src*="angular.js"], script[src*="angular.min.js"]')
      )
    );
  })()
) {
  window.postMessage({ singlePageAppCheck: true });
} else {
  window.postMessage({ singlePageAppCheck: false });
}
```

I'm not sure what it is or where it came from, and I can't really read it - does this look familiar to anyone, or is this a hack?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a malicious script. It's probably being added either by one of your plugins or by WordPress itself.

Comment: That's a relief to hear. If I publish the edits in the metabox, the script prints out.

Comment: Should I search my plugin library for the `singlePageAppCheck` function to find the offending plugin?

Comment: Or you could just disable all of your plugins, then check if the script is still there. If it's gone then you know that it's one of your plugins adding this to your website, so enable one of them and check again, repeat until the script reappears and you'll find your "culprit". (You may want to use the [Health Check & Troubleshooting](https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/) plugin and its [Troubleshooting mode](https://make.wordpress.org/support/handbook/appendix/troubleshooting-using-the-health-check/#troubleshooting) to do all this.)

Comment: Update - I found it was a browser extension. Thanks for your help, cabrerahector!

Comment: @Sackadelic Can you tell us what extension caused the problem? This came up for a client of ours.

Comment: @David Hammond it was Keeper password manager. They are working on a fix now, just escalated to the devs this morning.